# SQL: Select One column into a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Select ISO_2_LETTER_CODE 
from #TempTable
INTO ODBCTest
```

But i keep getting error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: so you want to copy that column to another column ? or just view it and the title should be some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
Select ISO_2_LETTER_CODE
INTO ODBCTest
From #TempTable
```

Comment: @asd - That's not what your original post said. Your syntax is still wrong. But you may need to do a Drop Table #TempTable first.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for SELECT INTO is:

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, 
INTO Table2
FROM Table1

So The syntax would be:

SELECT ISO_2_LETTER_CODE INTO ODBCTest FROM #TempTable